# y/n loop at the end of a function

Tags: c, macos

good evening,

Here is my code. I am making a little calculator but I'm battling at the end to make the function repeat with a y/n loop. I have looked at others but can't seem to get the right answer. 
Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int n, num1, num2, result;
  char answer;
  {
    printf("\nWhat operation do you want to perform?\n");
    printf("Press 1 for addition.\n");
    printf("Press 2 for subtraction.\n");
    printf("Press 3 for multiplication.\n");
    printf("Press 4 for division.\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Please enter a number.\n");
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    printf("Please enter the second number.\n");
    scanf("%d", &num2);
    switch(n)
    {
      case 1: result = num1 + num2;
              printf("The addition of the two numbers is %d\n", result );
              break;
      case 2: result = num1 - num2;
              printf("The subtraction of the two numbers is %d\n", result );
              break;
      case 3: result = num1 * num2;
              printf("The multiplication of the two numbers is %d\n", result );
              break;
      case 4: result = num1 / num2;
              printf("The division of the two numbers is %d\n", result );
              break;
      default: printf("Wrong input!!!");
    }
    printf("\nDo you want to continue, y/n?\n");
    scanf("%c", &answer);
    while(answer == 'y');

  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are using wrong while loop. Please see some sample example of while then you could do it correctly.

Comment: Wrap the whole thing in a post-tested loop.

Comment: I think you want a [`do/while`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_do_while_loop.htm) loop.

Comment: depending on the value of `answer` `while(answer == 'y');` is either an infinite loop or does nothing.  you might want to check out a `do while` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this code

```
  char answer;
  {
    printf("\nWhat operation do you want to perform?\n");
    //...
    //... more code
    //...
    printf("\nDo you want to continue, y/n?\n");
    scanf("%c", &answer);
    while(answer == 'y');

  }
```

Try to change it to:

```
  char answer;
  do {
    printf("\nWhat operation do you want to perform?\n");
    //...
    //... more code
    //...
    printf("\nDo you want to continue, y/n?\n");
    scanf("%c", &answer);
  } while(answer == 'y');
```

So the basic form is:

```
do {
    // code to repeat
} while (Boolean-expression);
```

BTW - You should always check the value returned by `scanf`

Example:

```
if (scanf("%c", &answer) != 1)
{
    // Add error handling
}
```

Also notice that you often want a space before `%c` to remove any white space (including newlines) in the input stream. Like

```
if (scanf(" %c", &answer) != 1)
{
    // Add error handling
}
```